# How to apply style in function of element property in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So I'm trying to do something like this :

```
<div :style="{photo.portrait: 'portraitStyle'}" :key="photo"></div>
```

with `portraitStyle` being a computed property which check if the element property portrait is true or false:

```
portraitStyle () {
    return this.portrait ? 'height: ' + (this.rowHeight*2+this.colPadding)+ 'px !important' : '';
},
```

I'm not sure this is the correct way of doing it?

My question could be also :

How to use element as reference for `this` in computed property instead of Vue component implementation?

Comment: check [VUe Guide: Class and Style Binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: @Sphinx Nothing helped me there except pointing to me that this was not a viable approach